# Uncaught ReferenceError when converting .js to .js.coffee

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, coffeescript

I am getting `Uncaught ReferenceError` for `map` for the following code after converting my `.js` to `.js.coffee` without changing anything in the flow or in the code it self.

My script runs just fine when using `.js`, no anymore in `.js.coffee`.

I am using GMAP API as well as snazzy infowindows, rails 5, ruby 2.4.

Do you have any idea why?

**EDIT**

I didn't put there the `mapOptions` variable for clarity sake, it's just a variable defined in my file storing GMAP Snazzy theme.

```
markersData = '<%= raw @places_markers.to_json %>'

  markers = []

  icon =
    path: 'M4.415,8.829c2.432,0,4.415-1.983,4.415-4.415 C8.829,1.983,6.846,0,4.415,0S0,1.983,0,4.415C0,6.846,1.983,8.829,4.415,8.829z'
    fillColor: '#2962FF'
    fillOpacity: 1
    anchor: new (google.maps.Point)(0, 0)
    strokeWeight: 1
    scale: 2

  initializeMap = ->
    map = new (google.maps.Map)(document.getElementById('places-map'), mapOptions)

    google.maps.event.addListener map, 'click', ->
      infoWindow.close()

    displayMarkers(markersData)


  createMarker = (latlng, markerInfowindow, icon) ->
    marker = new (google.maps.Marker)(
      map: map
      position: latlng
      icon: icon
      draggable: true)

    markers.push(marker)

    google.maps.event.addListener marker, 'click', ->
      iwContent = markerInfowindow

      infoWindow = new SnazzyInfoWindow(
        marker: marker
        content: iwContent
        placement: 'top'
        maxWidth: 400
        maxHeight: 200
      )

      infoWindow.open(map, marker)

  displayMarkers = (markersData) ->
    bounds = new (google.maps.LatLngBounds)
    places_coordinates = []

    i = 0
    while i < markersData.length
      latlng = new (google.maps.LatLng)(markersData[i].place_lat, markersData[i].place_lng)

      markerInfowindow = markersData[i].infowindow

      places_coordinates.push(latlng)

      createMarker(latlng, markerInfowindow, icon)

      bounds.extend(latlng)
      i++

    markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers)
    map.fitBounds(bounds)

  newLocation = (newLat, newLng) ->
    map.setCenter
      lat: newLat
      lng: newLng
    map.setZoom 15

  initializeMap()
```

Answer (score 1):

`map` is a local variable inside `initializeMap`:

```
initializeMap = ->
    map = new (google.maps.Map)(document.getElementById('places-map'), mapOptions)
    ...
```

so it isn't visible anywhere else unless you force it to be global. All variables in CoffeeScript are local unless you explicitly say otherwise.

You could make a class and make `map` an instance variable:

```
class YourMap
  constructor:
    @map = new google.maps.Map(...)

  # The rest of your code converted to methods goes here
```

or, since [CoffeeScript wraps your code in a self executing function](http://coffeescript.org/#lexical-scope) to maintain its scoping rules, you could declare `map` outside your functions:

```
map = undefined
markersData = '<%= raw @places_markers.to_json %>'
markers = []
#...
```

and then leave everything else alone.

Using a class would probably be considered more idiomatic in CoffeeScript.

Comment: Thanks for you feedback, really helps me moving forward. I jsut tried defining map as undefined inside my function, which, in this case, generates a `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error. I assume this is a kind of recursiveness issue, caused by a function calling another function. But in my case, `initializeMap` calls `displayMarkers` which calls  `createMarker`. I just don't see why this is an issue anymore (maybe the 6h spent on this make me blind...)

Comment: You would say `map = undefined` outside the function so that it could be shared.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I did declare it outside my function

Comment: There should be a stack trace to go with the exception.

Comment: Indeed, in my trace, I can see that I do generate my infowindows ` Rendered places/_infowindow.html.erb` for each marker. So this is good sign. I can also see the following: `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/snazzy-info-window.min.js.map"):`. I used `npm` to install the snazzy package and followed this instructions to call the package assets: https://blog.ravenxce.com/using-npm-with-rails/

Comment: And solve this problem by removing any reference to `snazzy-info-window.min.js.map` in snazzy js files, but still getting `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`. I wonder if this is due to a pure code issue or to a file import that somehow is not well done